# LinkedIn AdGroups API returning empty results

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to GET campaign groups that are in an AdAccount using python API.

I have generated access token from LinkedIn UI & it has a validity of 2 months.

This is one of the API that i tried. My AdAccount has ACTIVE campaign groups.

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&search.status.values[0]=ACTIVE&search.status.values[1]=DRAFT&sort.field=ID&sort.order=DESCENDING`

On every API call i am getting an empty result only.

`{'paging': {'start': 0, 'count': 10, 'links': [], 'total': 0}, 'elements': []}`

Could someone please help me how to retrieve Ads data from LinkedIn

Comment: paste the official documentation regarding this endpoint here please...

Comment: @MarceloGazzola please find the official documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups?tabs=http#search-for-campaign-groups

Comment: Issue is resolved now, had to generate the token from the LinkedIn account which has access to the campaign!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your post about this on upwork. I didn't applied there because I have no experience with python or LinkedIn ads.
Checking the docs looks like the params are optional so I guess you could do a:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search`

And you should be able to see all the campaigns that you have access to.
If you still get empty result you should check your permissions. Link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups?tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: Still getting empty response. Checked my permissions too. Token has r_ads, rw_ads & r_ads_reporting permissions. I think these should be enough to pull the ads. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, had to generate the token from the LinkedIn account which has access to the campaign!